# Erro ao instalar Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2013

:Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
A assinatura digital do objeto não pôde ser verificada.
```

Ao instalar o Visual Studio Professional 2013 em um notebook com Windows 8.1 Single Language

print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tirei um print agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O instalador que você baixou provavelmente **está corrompido** conforme está descrito [aqui](http://syedfrazali.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/visual-studio-2013-error-digital.html), experimente baixar novamente o instalador ou instale a partir da internet.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A corrupção tá passando dos limites já.