# Erro ao tentar instalar Visual Studio 2013: Acess Denied KB2829760

Tags: visual-studio

Estou tentando instalar o Visual Studio a partir da ISO `vs2013.5_ce_enu` que baixei, para poder dar prosseguimento com meus estudos em C#.

Porém, quando tento instalar, aparece um erro:

```
KB2829760
Access Denied
```

O sistema operacional que eu estou usando é o Windows 10.

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

O instalador é esse:

[image: Instalador do Visual Studio Comumunity 2013 (com atualização 5)]

**NOTA**: Não perguntei no SuperUser, porque não sou um expert em inglês, mas decidi perguntar, pois eu vi que existem perguntas similares aqui no site e que foram bem recebidas (não foi fechada ou não recebeu uma chuva de negativos).

[Erro ao instalar Visual Studio 2013 Professional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17211/erro-ao-instalar-visual-studio-2013-professional)

Comment: Vou tentar instalar novamente e vou postar aqui a tela que apresenta o erro

Comment: Provavelmente tem algo errado com a instalação do Windows ou alguma coisa não relacionada ao VS. Falta de espaço, por exemplo.

Comment: Nem brinca com "espaço faltando". 162 gb livres no meu notebook

Comment: Só fico pensando pra que instalar o 2013. No seu caso que não vai fazer nada em produção eu iria tentar instalar o 2016. Ah, esses Windows piratas que tem por aí modificados são todos melados :D

Comment: Foi a iso que o Randrade me passou, não tenho culpa, hehehe

Comment: Baixei o Windows 10 direto do site da microsoft. Só se a MS agora tá oferecendo o Windows Pirata, hehehehe. Lutando para instalar um appzinho... Cara, por isso eu sou fã do Linux

Comment: Eu sou fã do Windows porque ele não me dá nenhum problema :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que seu erro se deve a problemas com permissões incorretas na lista de controle de acesso (ACL) em algumas partes do *registry*.

O kb2829760 chama-se Visual Studio 2013 Updates. Já que a informação de erro aponta para problemas de segurança, verifique o seguinte:

1. Certifique-se que você está executando a instalação do Visual Studio como administrador;
2. Use a ferramenta `subacl` e um script para dar permissões adequadas a todos os arquivos e entradas no *registry*, de acordo com esta referência:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/09/04/solving-setup-errors-by-using-the-subinacl-tool-to-repair-file-and-registry-permissions.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/solving-setup-errors-by-using-the-subinacl-tool-to-repair-file-and-registry-permissions)

[Fonte](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8da32b6e-2e3c-4d7a-9c88-fa0feae0c6ec/visual-studio-express-setup-failed-setup-engine-access-denied-user-cancelled-installation-of-a?forum=vssetup).

Comment: Foi só fazer a pergunta, que a bagaça começou a instalar. Tá de brincadeira, Ruindows!